# Get only one line from a web page

Tags: php

Hi, I have this file [test1.php](http://inviatapenet.gethost.ro/sop/test1.php) and in the other file [test.php](http://inviatapenet.gethost.ro/sop/test.php) I have this 
`php` code running:

```
<?php
$file = "http://inviatapenet.gethost.ro/sop/test1.php";
$line = '0';
if($f = fopen($file, 'r')){
  $line = fgets($f); // read until first newline
  fclose($f);
}
echo $line;
?>
```

The idea is to get just the second line of the web page test1.php.

> Second Line

I've tried to change the `$line = '2';` but no affect, it just displays the  first line.
I need Help.

Comment: Right, because you're just `fget`ting the first line, you're not using your `$line` variable anywhere. Try using it in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Obviously, change only the value of `$linetofetch`:

```
<?php
// Write here the number of the line you want to fetch.
$linetofetch = 2;

$file = "http://inviatapenet.gethost.ro/sop/test1.php";
$currentline = 1;
if($f = fopen($file, 'r')){
  while ($currentline <= $linetofetch) {
    $line = fgets($f); // read until first newline
    $currentline++;
    }
  fclose($f);
  }
echo $line;
?>
```

Comment: This dosen't worck! it give me errors :  fclose(): 3 is not a valid stream resource

Comment: Sorry, the `fclose` had to be outside the loop, corrected but Dale answer is better anyway (;

Comment: But your response helps me better.

Comment: Wow, thanks, can I ask why? If you really want to choose this one, please at least consider upvoting Dale's answer, which is better.

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos Both our answers are "better", I've just used different means to achieve the same result :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`file`](http://php.net/file) which reads a file into an array, you can then grab whichever line you want by using the index you want.

For example:

data.txt:

```
line one
line two
line three
line four
```

PHP code:

```
$file = file('data.txt');
echo $file[1]; // echo line number 2, remember arrays start at 0!
```

Updated PHP code for new versions (5.4):

```
echo file('data.txt')[1];
```

Comment: Nice, +1 since I didn't even know about this. The version for 5.4 should be much more efficient, right? (since no file is actually being stored into variable)

Comment: I assume so yes, also it's a one liner which is way high on the cool points :))

Comment: @Frank The whole file is still *read into memory* and stored in an array before `[1]` accesses the data. It's not any more efficient, it's just syntactic sugar. The data is then potentially garbage collected soon through since no variable is referring to it.

Comment: Also you can't access it again later using the one liner approach, it just looks cool.